# How to change uvm verbosity for an object in component

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I encountered an issue when setting verbosity for an object in component.
I want to set the verbosity of specific components (uvm_test_top.env.subenv_a) to UVM_HIGH, command line argument is as below:

```
1.+UVM_VERBOSITY=UVM_LOW

2.+uvm_set_verbosity=*subenv_a*,_ALL_,UVM_HIGH,build,0
```

The object (object_a) will do some configurations in build phase of component: `subenv_a.`

I didn't saw the UVM_HIGH info in object_a is printed and the UVM_HIGH info for all the components in component subenv_a will be printed.

Seems that command "+uvm_set_verbosity" just take effect on component,but not object in component.

So what should i do to print UVM_HIGH info for an object in component.

Thanks
Ken

Answer (score 3):

Only classes derived from `uvm_component` have knowledge of their parentage. By *knowledge* I mean `uvm_component` is set up to link parents with children as a database that can be traversed via a named hierarchy. You can:

- Derive your `object_a` from `uvm_report_object` instead of `uvm_object`. Then from your component, do `object_a_h.set_report_handler(get_report_handler);`. Now all messages from `object_a` appear as if they came from your component and share the same report settings.
- Pass `this` as a context to your `object_a`, and use the `uvm_info_context()` macros instead of `uvm_info`. This has the same effect as above.
- Use a unique message ID in `object_a` and add a extra `+uvm_set_verbosity` switch for that ID.
- Derive your `object_a` from `uvm_component` instead of `uvm_object` and make your component its parent. This might be the simplest solution, but has the most overhead if there many of these objects.

Comment: Thanks Dave, i used the first method.